# howto : output utf-8(kannada) characters in windows terminal using java

Tags: java, utf-8, console, terminal, indic

am working on a java(tomcat) app. that sometimes writes to stdout. But I notice that indic languages(say, [kannada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_language)) turn out as ?????? characters on the std. windows console(terminal) on Windows Vista (SP1 Home premium 64-bit).

I know that I could run tomcat from within emacs(GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.0.6001)) so I could see the tomcat console output from within emacs. Emacs renders kannada OK(although with errors).

But it would be nice if I could launch tomcat from outside of emacs if I could.

I realize that I could run tomcat from within eclipse as well (where you can control the console encoding) but again, it would be nice to launch tomcat from outside of eclipse, if I could.

So, what do developers who want to see their indic language (which takes 3 byte characters to render) do ? Also, What tail utilities do they use ?

I tried running the command chcp 65001. But after I do this, catalina.bat does NOT runat all (exits with no output) :-(

P.S : I'm running as "Administrator" user if that is of any help.

Thanks for any tips and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I find that cmd.exe is NOT capable of printing indic characters!

Comment: In other words, you didn't found any capable font?

Answer (score 2):

You're restricted by the **font** used in the cmd. The font used simply doesn't have those glyphs available. You can [hack the registry](http://www.google.com/search?q=HKLM%2FSoftware%2FMicrosoft%2FWindows+NT%2FCurrentVersion%2FConsole%2FTrueTypeFont) to add more fonts, but you still have to find a font which supports those glyphs. Rather let Tomcat log to a logfile and use a viewer which has fonts supporting those glyphs (e.g. Arial , Verdana, etc). You can try [TailXP](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Keylogger-Monitoring/Tail-XP.shtml) if you want file tailing in Windows.